# How to install a package with pip locally?

Tags: python, pip, cython

Hello I've installed a local version of pip using

```
python get-pip.py --user
```

After that I can't find the path of pip, so I run:

```
python -m pip install --user Cython
```

Finally I can't import Cython

```
import Cython 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
```

Comment: Have you tried using a virtualenv? or just using `which pip`?

Comment: what does `which python` output? Presuming you are using a unix based OS

Comment: `which pip` output `/usr/bin/which: no pip in` and `which python` output `~/python/Python-3.4.1/python`

Comment: I have tried using virtualenv but it doesn't work with python 3.4 `ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable`

Answer (score 0):

Use virtualenv, it is used to create isolated python environments (check this quick guide http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ )

Comment: if I want to install virtualenv, I need to have pip running first right?

Comment: Add pip to your PATH env variable. It should be in ~/.local/bin

Comment: I have only this empty folder ".local/lib/python3.4/site-packages"

Comment: So you can't run sudo python get-pip.py?

Comment: Wait a minute, you are using python 3.4? This version comes pre-installed with pip.

Comment: Yes it's python 3.4 but I can't find pip. It's a cluster and I can't use sudo.

Comment: Does pyenv work?(also new feature) "pyvenv ~/new_virtualenvironment" then "source ~/new_virtualenvironment/bin/activate". It should also include pip

Comment: Python 3.4.1 for some unknown reason I can't find pip nor pyenv

Comment: Ok, I can preinstalled pip using `python -m pip install --user Cython` but then I can't import Cython

Comment: Now it's working after some pain and adding this line `install_lib=~/usr/lib/python2.7.8/site-packages` to the hidden file .pydistutils.cfg in the home directory. Any explanation on why this isn't done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install --user Cython
```

should probabably be

```
pip install --user cython
```

Comment: I can't find my pip binary, that's why I use "python -m pip"